# The usage of articles with nouns modified by an adjective

Tags: grammar, articles

Please help.

1) *"I sat into a car. Having sat into **a nice car** I started home"*

2) *"I sat into a car. Having sat into **the nice car** I started home"*

3) *"I saw a car. **A nice car** was very clean and shiny"*

4) *"I saw a car. **The nice car** was very clean and shiny"*

- Can they both be used for the second mention?
- If yes, what is the difference in meaning?

P.s. The way I see it - saying "a nice car" is appropriate in 1 and 3, like a way of saying "*what was a nice car (referring to the car already introduced)...*" or it can also be the first mention of another car.

Saying "the nice car" in 2 and 4 - "*what was the only nice car within context*" or it can have another meaning - just the second mention of that car, that is not nessessary the only one.

But all of the above are just my guesses and I'd be glad if you could clarify it. Thanks.

Comment: 1) and 2) should use "in" in place of "into". You get "into" but you sit "in".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have multiple answers as your question has many points. Easiest first:

Forget the bit about the adjective. Seriously. As far as the articles are concerned, it's not relevant.

With sentence (1) and (3) there is no "connection" between the two sentences. 
Your assumption that it's something like a shortened relative clause is not true. (Example follows later). So, yes, you are talking about two cars, which might or might not be the same. Very confusing for the reader.

Sentence (2) and (4) are ok, because it's clear that you are talking about the same car (just introduced). Still, it would be better if you'd use a demonstrative ("this" car) instead of the article. So:

> 4) I saw a car. This nice car was very clean and shiny.

Also, it sounds more natural if you move the adjective to the first mentioning of the car. Then, as you already mentioned the car, a pronoun will be enough in the second part:

> I saw a nice car. It was very clean and shiny.

If you want to further describe the car (as you suggested), use not "what", but "which". Also, the two sentences should be "closer", so join them:

> I saw a nice car, which was very clean and shiny.

Similar line of thought leads to:

> I sat in a nice car. Having sat in it I drove home. ->
>   Having sat in a nice car, I drove home.

Comment: This is about as concise as you could get with such a broad-ranging question.